# Get the list of leaf nodes in fancy tree

Tags: fancytree

I'm using https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/ in my project. How to get the list of leaf nodes of the fancy tree at the given moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this pattern:

```
var leafNodes = [];

tree.visit(function(node){
    if ( !node.hasChildren() ) {
        leafNodes.push(node);
    }
});
```